# Is it necessary or advisable to preserve SSL certificates when moving to a new server?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have one domain that I'm serving a site on from a VPS. I used certbot to get certificates and automatically set up TLS on the nginx server. If I'm moving the site to a new VPS is there any reason to preserve the certificates and letsencrypt account information and migrate them or can I just run certbot again on the new server? If I am going to go from scratch and not migrate anything is there anything I need to do beforehand apart from revoking the existing certificates?

Comment: When I built a new server I just requested new certificates for all my websites through Let's Encrypt. I didn't have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or can I just run certbot again on the new server?

as long you don't use certificate pinning (HPKP) there is no reason to carry old certificate. Just run certbot on new server and acquire new certificate.

> apart from revoking the existing certificates

If you can safely destroy the key on existing system, I wouldn't even bother with revocation.